# Linux VNC doesnt accepting my password

Tags: linux, password, vnc

I set up a tight VNC server.
I used this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-14-04

The VPS is hosted on Digitalocean.
The VNC server is running.
After typing `service vncserver start` it says:

```
    root@vpn:~# service vncserver start
 * Starting vncserver for user 'demo' on localhost:1...
New 'X' desktop is vpn:1

Starting applications specified in /home/demo/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/demo/.vnc/vpn:1.log

root@vpn:~#
```

But after SSH tunneling with putty and logging in with vnc viewer it simply said (so no credentials won´t be entered):

```
This server does not have a valid password enabled. Until a password is set, incoming connections cannot be accepted.
```

User account demo have its own password and password for vncserver is chosen, too.
Any solutions ?

EDIT: If I dont use SSH tunneling method, I get

```
Connection was refused by host computer
```

Answer (score 1):

What I remember from using a VNCSERVER with password is that the password must be alphanumeric and cannot be very long. Could have been changed in the meanwhile, but I thought that the maximum length was something like 8 characters and special characters were not allowed. Could you try to simplify your password using only alphanum-chars and then try to login again?

Also, the guide you mensioned did not mention anything about a password, did you set this?

> login as the user, in this case "demo" in the CLI and then type

```
vncpasswd
```

Comment: I read about that and i have tried 6 characters long password for this. Now its not answering anyway.

Comment: "This server does not have a valid password enabled" is the error reported when you have not provisioned a password with vncpasswd. When using VNC as described above, this needs to be run as the user owning the X window session you are connecting to.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience when I tried to enter '+' from numberpad. But if I enter '+' from the big pad VNC Linux recognize it as correct. Besides, some special symbols would cause an error too. So VNC is not totally reliable.